# Make VLC play all of a sound clip?

Tags: audio, mp3, vlc-media-player, wav

In VLC 1.0.5, sound files (mp3 and wav) are not playing completely. I think the leading .1 sec and trailing .5 second, more or less, are not playing. I remember this behavior from some years ago, but am not sure the app or how i fixed it. Seems like there was some setting that was causing it to clip the sounds, but can't find or remember it. The Zune Software and Windows Media Player work fine. Windows 7 Pro, if it matters.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like some sort of cross fade or fade in/fade out setting. I've looked at the Preferences buy can't find anything either.

Comment: @ChrisF, "fade" rings a bell, but not sure.

Comment: [Fixed](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=72111#p287752) in VLC 1.2.0.   Broken in 1.1.9.